# how to get select event of element in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

could you please tell me how to get select event of element in angular  ? 
I make a demo using this this github
https://github.com/codecapers/AngularJS-FlowChart

live demo 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16408368/WebUI_FlowChart/index.html

In demo user can select node and delete the node..I want to get click event of node .I want to get selected object.
can we get selected object or click event of node in angular js

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/vTgDa3AfY8aiWVgUgZf8?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="cntrl" style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
     <div style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
     <flow-chart
        style="margin: 5px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
        chart="chartViewModel"
        >
    </flow-chart>
    </div>
   </div>
```

any update ?

Comment: Can't you attach ng-click="someFunc" to every node and in your view model capture that event?

Answer (score 0):

Is that flowchart directive a 3rd party or did you build it?

Could edit the directive if it is not 3rd-party and add a click event:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDocumentClick', 
    ['$window', '$document', '$log',
    function($window, $document, $log) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          $document.bind('click', function(event) {
            $log.info(event);
            if (angular.element(event.target).hasClass('myClass')) {
              $window.alert('Foo!');
            }
          })
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: This is also an option: you could add  ng-click="myFunction($event)" to the element

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so could you up vote my answer or set it as the selected answer?